# debugging android app via eclipse on bluestacks app player

Tags: android, debugging, emulation, bluestacks

I have read a few articles that BlueStacks App Player can be used to debug android apps via Eclipse, instead of the default android emulator.
[Example article](http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php?topic=2665.0)

But I think this refers to the Windows version, I was unable to get to it work on MacOS. Does anyone know how to debug using BlueStacks/eclipse on MAC?

Comment: To connect to **BlueStacks 4**, the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804751/7621674) (of a related question) may be helpful.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
adb connect localhost:10001
```

should do the trick.

Comment: didn't work for me, I got a new device but it appears offline

Comment: Or:

adb connect localhost:5555

Comment: for me, just `adb connect localhost` default port 5555 worked.

Comment: Running bluestacks 2 to debug now and localhost:5555 is working :)

Comment: how about the bluestacks 4?

Answer (score 15):

Well, you can try another way:

1) First, open the DDMS via `Window->Open Perspective->DDMS` under Eclipse.

2) Then open BlueStacks App Player.(leave it opens)

3) After that switch back to Eclipse and you should notice there're two emulator under the `Device` tab.
[image]

Then click `Reset adb` under the small triangle at the `Device` tab.
[image]

After a few seconds, the another one emulator will disappear and you can proceed to the next step.
[image]

4) Then return back through `Window->Open Perspective->Java` under Eclipse.

5) Select your project and right click on it, choose `Debug As->Debug Configurations`
[image]

6) Under `Android Application` select your configuration or create a new one. On the `Target` tab choose `Always prompt to pick device`After this, select `Apply` then `Debug`.
[image]

7) Then select BlueStacks emulator in the prompt window, and finally select `OK`.

Alternatively, you can also open the BlueStacks App Player before Eclipse using the above steps(with minor changes).

For more info, visit the below links.(However, in Chinese...)

http://www.cnblogs.com/hbbbs/archive/2012/10/30/2746950.html
http://www.cnblogs.com/hbbbs/archive/2012/10/30/2746979.html

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: The hint of "resetting adb" did it for me.  Thanks @Herks.

Answer (score 5):

```
C:\>cd Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555
connected to 127.0.0.1:5555

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>
```

Comment: this actually worked when... all of the above have failed

Answer (score 2):

Run Bluestacks.

open **Command Prompt** in Windows.

Go to **Platform-tools** using following command.

```
cd C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

then write:

```
adb devices
```

With SDK tools 27 and later!
You get a list of devices *detected* by adb .. if BlueStacks-4 is installed you should see the device listed (emulator-555x).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users: localhost:5037 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

BlueStacks bundles its own copy of `adb`, `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\BlueStacks\HD-adb.exe`. You can `connect localhost` with it, or any other command. BlueStacks 3 uses the default port `5555`.

Comment: With BluStacks-4, I don't recommend using shipped adb ..instead make sure Android build in adb is up to date as it usually automatically detects Blustacks-4 (happens to be emulator-5554!)