# Is BlueStacks really an emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-x86, bluestacks

I know that using Bluestacks App Player we can run android application on Windows. What I want to know that is,

"Is BlueStacks an emulator or a stripped down version of android operating system or a stripped down version of android-x86?

Because it’s really faster than other emulators like eclipse and so on. And I actually want to know how this application works and How it can run faster than the emulators used in Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueStacks

Comment: @kgandroid I know! & read it before asking this question. I actually want to know how this application works that can run faster than eclipse or etc?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Bluestacks is an Android Emulator as mentioned in their website and in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueStacks#App_Player). And you can able to use it for development purposes just like other IDE emulators. Please have a look at he following posts on,

[How to debug apps in Bluestacks from Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899794/debugging-android-app-via-eclipse-on-bluestacks-app-player) and

[How to connect Bluestacks as an emulator and test out apps in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598577/connect-bluestacks-to-android-studio)

They are using [LayerCake](https://layercake.cs.washington.edu/) architecture to make it run the emulator faster in computer.

Answer (score 0):

Blue stack is not an emulator it is designed to enable Android applications to run on Windows PCs, Macintosh computers and televisions.
You can not compare Bluestack and Eclipse..
Both are different.
You cannot develop applications using BlueStack but you can develop it using Eclipse..

Comment: so what is BlueStacks?
I mean if ti isn't an emulator, what is really it?

Comment: so how can it works on windows? because as you know android applications need Dalvic VM, but windows has JVM.

Comment: Yes true..BlueStacks support multi-OS runtime with breakthrough virtualization technology.

Comment: I am not much aware about how Bluestacks really works.I just know that it support Multiple OS.