# How to use ADB if you don't have an option "Enable USB Debugging" on Bluestacks App Player?

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to run adb commands like shell, push, pull, etc?

Comment: have you tried tapping 7 times on about to make `Enable USB Debugging` appear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debugging android app via eclipse on bluestacks app player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899794/debugging-android-app-via-eclipse-on-bluestacks-app-player)

Comment: @Afshin I'm running Bluestacks. I don't think there is "Build number" on "About Device".

Comment: @bvgffhjn look into the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899794/debugging-android-app-via-eclipse-on-bluestacks-app-player there are several answers dealing with the adb connection you are looking for