# How do you adb to bluestacks 4?

Tags: android, adb, bluestacks

I'd like to connect to android emulator on bluestacks 4 with adb. 
but I've got an error with `adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell`

checking devices.

```
$ adb.exe devices
List of devices attached
BH901...      device
CB512...      unauthorized





emulator-5554   device
```

once I shutdown bluestacks window, the `emulator-5554` will be hidden from above command's result. thus I think `emulator-5554` means bluestacks.

then commnad as below to use adb.

```
$ adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell
error: closed
```

but as you know, an error occured.

Comment: Can you disconnect all devices, run `adb kill-server` then run your emulator and execute `adb devices`

Comment: @TomDickson I did. I got the same error `error: closed`. `deb devices` output is the same result as above as well.

Comment: Bluestacks is very buggy software; sometimes it works, sometimes it is not, and it is complex to say what is the reason.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First, in Bluestacks, go to Settings -> Preferences -> Enable Android Debug Bridge (ADB). Like this:

[image]

At this point, Bluestacks enables its adb functionality and exposes itself to the localhost at port 5555 (the default port)

So, in your command line, type **`adb connect localhost:5555`** and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can't see this option. http://prntscr.com/o583ya. I have installed Android Studio, Android USD Drivers etc. ADB work for android phones. But, for Bluestacks it not works. and i can't see the mentioned option. Any idea what is it?

Comment: Same for me blueSTacks 4.32.75.1002, doesn't show the option

Comment: It may be needed to restart BlueStacks after checking 'Enable ADB'.

Comment: And restart adb server.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but for the record, I didn't have the option in Bluestacks until I installed android development tools.

Answer (score 7):

I did exactly as the chosen approved answer but i still could not connect my android studio to Bluestack 4. Hence i think the problem both of us are encountering could be due to bluestack device ip has changed. (Even if you had detect the device using adb devices command earlier on). Each time i open up my bluestack emulator, i notice that its ip is always different. Hence that could be one of the reason why you could not add adb to bluestack4.

The following step works for me. I am using windows 10, Android Studio 4.0.1, Bluestacks 4.200.

1. find your android studio sdk platform tool folder. For me its is
   custom installed in my D drive. for example->
   D:\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
2. right click on adb.exe and run as administrator. (click on yes if
   a pop up ask if you would like to make changes to your devices.
   After that you would only see another pop up that suddenly
   disappear.)
3. open Bluestacks. Run your selected emulator (samsung/pixel etc).
   Ensure that you have enable "Enable Android Debug Bridge (ADB) in
   the emulator preferences.
4. open platform tools folder path: Click on address bar, alternatively press Alt + D. Now when address bar is highlighted, type cmd in the bar. Press Enter key.
5. enter the following command->adb connect xxxxxxxxxxx
   where xxxxxx is your device localhost ip. (see attach pic. My device ip is
   127.0.0.1:xxxxx hence my command is ->adb connect 127.0.0.1:xxxxx
6. continue with the following command->adb devices
   you would see your bluestack emulator device. same ip listed.
7. open your andriod studio. you would be able to see your bluestack
   emulator

[[image: enter bluestack adb preferences1]

[image: android studio with bluestack emulator]

Answer (score 3):

And I have test bluestack 4 in windows 10 and enable the adb permission in bluestacks 4 settings. It works for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This choice doesn't exist in Bluestacks 4

Answer (score 3):

1. After enabling adb in blue stack
2. go to platform-tools folder

> e.g. "C:\Users\***Your Username***\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools"

3. run this in cmd "adb connect localhost:5555" or whatever port given by bluestack.

---

or just run directly from Win+R

> "C:\Users\***Your
> Username***\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb connect
> localhost:5555"

n.b. localhost = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

On BlueStack 5 it should be in Advanced -> Android Debug Bridge