# How do you adb to multiinstance bluestacks 4? What is the adb-port of the secondary instances?

Tags: android, adb, bluestacks

How do I adb to second and third and so forth instances of bluestacks?

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317727/how-do-you-adb-to-bluestacks-4) one has to enable Adb in preferences of each bluestack instance, then possibly do

`adb connect localhost:5555`

This will connect to the first instance. `adb devices` now shows

```
emulator-5554   device
localhost:5555  device
```

Both being the same bluestack instance, namely the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, seems I found the instances.

It could look like the instances are on 5555 + idx*10, where idx is the index af the bluestack instance. I found some with this powershell line `foreach ($i in 555..579) { adb connect localhost:"${i}5"}`

Comment: I found the answer as I was writing it, so I wanted to share the knowledge. If others have more details or actually know the above to be correct, I'll accept that anwser.