# How can I fix bluestacks adb error closed issue?

Tags: python, adb, bluestacks

Im trying to run a command using python thru adb on bluestacks but recieve an error closed response even though when i check adb devices it shows bluestacks. This works fine on bluestacks 3 but not on bluestacks 4. I have attached a screenshot

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Open Emulator Settings -> Options -> enable android debug bridge (ADB).

Comment: I tried to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317727/how-do-you-adb-to-bluestacks-4 but i dont have that setting on my bluestacks settings to enable it

Comment: Your BlueStack Version ? The answer is already on the link, if you don't see the option it may be related to the version. Download the latest updated version.