# how do I connect flutter to bluestacks 5 emulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, bluestacks

How can I connect Flutter with VS Code to emulator BlueStacks 5? Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317727/how-do-you-adb-to-bluestacks-4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you adb to bluestacks 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317727/how-do-you-adb-to-bluestacks-4)