# Bluestacks device not found on VsCode and Android Studio on Mac OS

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, bluestacks

I installed Bluestacks on mac Os as an emulator for flutter apps.

I was able to debug apps on it a couple of times but once my computer was restarted,I could no longer see the device connected on VSCode and Android studio.

VSCODE

[image: device not found on VSCode]

Android Studio

[image: device not found on Android Studio]

I have re-installed bluestacks but no luck. 
I have double checked that **Android debug bridge is enabled** on bluestacks

[image: Android debug bridge is enabled on bluestacks]

Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [debugging android app via eclipse on bluestacks app player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899794/debugging-android-app-via-eclipse-on-bluestacks-app-player)

Comment: Dear Mariano, 
Thanks for your response.
It doesn't .